# vim colorscheme does not load

Tags: linux, vim

i am trying to use a specific colorscheme for my normal user. both are sunos, if it matters. 
in the first case, i created a .vim/vim73 directory and copied the disired colorscheme into the directory. 
and the second case i am doing the same. 
one difference between these cases is, that in the latter one exist an directory /usr/share/vim73/colors while it doesn't exist in the first place.

i already checked the runtimepath.
in case 1 it is 
 runtimepath=~/.vim,~/.vim/vimfiles,~/.vim/vim73,~/.vim/vimfiles/after,~/.vim/after
in the 2nd case it is
  runtimepath=~/.vim,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/share/vim/vim73,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after,~/.vim/after

i tried already vim -V9mylog.txt example.py it only says colorscheme not found in the mentioned directories of the rtp.

so, why does it not work in the second case? does anybody know how to proceed or to get further debug information. Any suggestion how to narrow it down is welcome.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latter runtimepath does not have the `.vim/vim73`, so if you put the colorscheme there, it will not be found.

I would recommend to put the colorscheme into `~/.vim/colors/NAME.vim`; then you can use it via `:colorscheme NAME`.

I don't know where the `vim73` comes from, but as part of your user configuration, that's odd. Most plugins have a version guard in the script itself; especially in color schemes, there should not be anything version-dependent.

Finally, Vim 7.3 is from 2010 and *quite* outdated. You're missing out on many useful added features and bugfixes.